# Wifi randomly disconnects then immediately reconnects

Tags: networking, wireless, 22.04

Several times an hour the Wifi connection drops.  In some instances the "Authentication required" for the network appears on top of everything else; in others it reconnects automatically within several seconds (in rare cases up to a minute).  When using Zoom, it happens once every couple of minutes, which is not very convenient as this is precisely the place where I'd like the connection to be stable.

The issue is not with the home network, because other devices (mobile phones and laptops - both on Windows and on Linux) never have Wifi issues.

Dell Precision, Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

```
# lshw -class network
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlp0s20f3
       version: 01
       serial: zz:zz:zz:zz:zz:zz
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.15.0-52-generic firmware=64.97bbee0a.0 so-a0-gf-a0-64.uc ip=192.168.0.227 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:620-61f irq:16 memory:6289294000-6289297fff
```

The repeating patterns in the system logs at the times matching the disconnections look like this:

```
# journalctl -k
Nov 08 08:50:14 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx for new auth to yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
Nov 08 08:50:14 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: authenticate with yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
Nov 08 08:50:14 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: send auth to yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy (try 1/3)
Nov 08 08:50:14 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: authenticated
Nov 08 08:50:14 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: associate with yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy (try 1/3)
Nov 08 08:50:14 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: RX ReassocResp from yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy (capab=0x1411 status=0 aid=1)
Nov 08 08:50:14 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: associated
Nov 08 08:50:14 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy
```

or this:

```
Nov 08 08:50:50 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: disconnect from AP yy:yy:yy:yy:yy:yy for new auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Nov 08 08:50:50 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Nov 08 08:50:50 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: send auth to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
Nov 08 08:50:50 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: authenticated
Nov 08 08:50:50 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: associate with xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (try 1/3)
Nov 08 08:50:50 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: RX ReassocResp from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (capab=0x511 status=0 aid=5)
Nov 08 08:50:50 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: associated
Nov 08 08:50:51 <redacted> kernel: wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 14 (17 - 3) dBm as advertised by xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

(The `xx`s and `yy`s are two different addresses; I'm not sure why I have two of them.)

The solution from here ([Ubuntu 20.04 wifi randomly disconnecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1285997/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-randomly-disconnecting)) - disable automatic suspend - doesn't seem to have any effect.

The solution from somewhere else - edit `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` to say `wifi.powersave = disabled` - doesn't either.

I didn't try a solution from here:
[Ubuntu 20.04 wifi randomly disconnecting after update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1323000/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-randomly-disconnecting-after-update)
because it's about a Realtek card while I have Intel's "Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi", so I have no idea which drivers I am supposed to install.

What else can I try?

Comment: This looks like you have 2 Access Points, and your client is roaming between them. This may happen due to different signal strength. – or a bad roaming algorithm in the driver. Your Options: 1) Try to switch off one of the AP. 2) Configure a AP MAC in wpasupplicant (may not work via netplan). 3) if these Aps work on different channels you may configure a fixed channel in netplan.

Comment: Probably the 2.4 gHz and 5 gHz segments of your router. Please check my troublesgooting steps here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1362518/unable-to-connect-to-any-wifi-network-detected-in-xubuntu/1362570#1362570  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Setting the fixed channel helped.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a duplicate of [Loss of connectivity swapping between APs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254305/loss-of-connectivity-swapping-between-aps).  The issue got resolved after setting BSSID to a fixed value (one of the AP addresses) in Settings -> Wi-Fi ->  -> Identity -> BSSID.